# How to make a method to detect if a variable changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I declared `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *data;` in the h file, and pass an `NSString` from another class to "data". I want to detect if "data" is updated so I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
-(void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key {  

    [super didChangeValueForKey:key];
    if ( [key isEqualToString:@"data"] ) {
        // do something     
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to figure this out?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=cocoa+key+value+observation+guide

Comment: If you want to detect the change just within the class that declares the property then you can create a custom setter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this is to use **Key-Value Observation**.

Say you have an object `myObject` with a property `data` then you can do something like this...

```
[self.myObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"data" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Then you have the method...

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    // if you observer multiple properties then they will all fire this method
    // so you need to determine that the right property is being observed

    if (object == self.myObject
        && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
        // if you are here then you know the object that changed is myObject
        // and the property is the data property.

        id theNewData = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        // this is the new state of the data
        // you can also get the old state by using different options when adding the observer.
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [in the Apple documentation about KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use key value coding - this use a lot in UI update ref use this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)